# Dailymotion Player for private videos

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

We're building apps to play Dailymotion videos from our account and need to play non-public videos with the embedded Dailymotion player (or HTML5 video, but that seems not possible from what i have read so far).

Our PHP script should read all clips from a playlist and pass them to the HTML5/JS frontend to setup the player. This should work without any user interactive authentification, but only with the API keys and secret values, since the PHP code will be executed automatically from the HTML5/JS app. Of course the keys are not public, since they are stored only on the server for the PHP code.

in VIMEO this works through the API keys and also you can set videos to private but allow embedding them on specific domains.

questions are:
1) can we access our non public videos through PHP without user authentification
2) can we play our non public videos through the DM player?

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

On dailymotion, a private video is only viewable by you as it does not appear on your channel page. It is possible to share it with other users and play it by using its private id. Beware that when you disclose the private id or private url, the video can no longer be considered as "private".

To get this private id, you can request the following field on the `video` object in the API (the request must be authentified, but this is what you do in your php script):

- `private_id`. Then you can use it to play the video in the player.
- you can also request the `url`. If authentified, this request will provide the private url of the video on dailymotion.com

About the HTML5 dailymotion player, you can suscribe to the beta at https://www.dailymotion.com/player